# Notification Error "The method setProgress(int, int, boolean) is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder"

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know how to show a progress bar update in notification bar while downloading a file?

```
    Context context = MyClass.this.getApplicationContext();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) 
                                context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification updateComplete = new Notification();
    updateComplete.icon         = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    updateComplete.tickerText   = "Starting to download...";
    updateComplete.when         = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Intent notificationIntent   = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                                                        notificationIntent, 0);
    String contentTitle         = "Download"; 
    updateComplete.setLatestEventInfo
                      (context, contentTitle, "downloading...", contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify("yyy",1, updateComplete);
```

Comment: I reverted the [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1999128#./1999128) because it was invalid. Folks, if you suggest edits, why do you change strings? This makes no sense. And changing personal formatting preferences is really also a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample that should help you : http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/display-progress.html

Comment: Thanks! But Im having an error with .setProgress it says "The method setProgress(int, int, boolean) is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder". And also with the mBuilder.build() "The method build() is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder"

Comment: which is the android version you want your app on ? Also have you added in the support library ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reference my implements in my project:
Notification handler:
https://code.google.com/p/wifi-scanner/source/browse/src/com/shixunaoyou/wifiscanner/update/DownloadNotificationHandler.java

and download service:
https://code.google.com/p/wifi-scanner/source/browse/src/com/shixunaoyou/wifiscanner/update/DownloadUpdateService.java